# Rails single table inheritance ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I tried changing a User type to "nil" and keep getting this error message now:

> The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'nil'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite User.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.

```
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:161:in `rescue in find_sti_class'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:155:in `find_sti_class'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:144:in `discriminate_class_for_record'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:50:in `instantiate'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:48:in `block in find_by_sql'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `block in each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:48:in `map'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:48:in `find_by_sql'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:603:in `exec_queries'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:487:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:231:in `to_a'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/bullet-4.13.1/lib/bullet/active_record41.rb:10:in `to_a'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:479:in `find_last'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@rails-4.0.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:165:in `last'
```

I understand why it's happening and I do want the single table inheritance to occur but it won't even let me override it Rails Console. I'm trying to change the User type back to what I need and it immediately gives me that message. Even if I do User.find(*myID*) it won't pull up my data.

Any way I can just tell it to override it and change the type?

Edit:

I tried:

```
User.last (I was the last user)

User.find(*myId*)
```

It won't even let me do `User.last.destroy` or `User.destroy_all`, giving me the same error above each time in the console.

I also tried creating a model called "nil" that inherits from User and still nothing.

Comment: Did you write `"nil"` or `nil`? The latter should translate into SQL's `NULL`. Provide the code samples you have tried and exact output.

Comment: @D-side I actually wrote "nil" so it's probably looking for an actual type of "nil" - I tried creating a new model that's actually called "nil" that inherits from User and it still won't let me make changes, I'm assuming because it's lowercase now.

Comment: It's likely true. Still, snippets of the code you are running in the console (and the output) will help. Add them to the question. By the way, code is designated in questions by indenting it with 4 spaces.

Comment: Ok I added the commands I used above to access my User record, console gives me the same exact error every time, as well as my Rails error message.

Comment: Try `User.where(type: "nil").update_all(type: nil)`

Comment: Yes!! That did it! Thanks! Write that as an answer so it can be accepted as the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you messed up a little :)

Rails' Single Table Inheritance expects the exact class name in `type` field. Since `"nil"` does not specify a valid `User` subclass, you have created objects that make no sense in terms of STI.

It's easy to fix. Select all the errorneous entries (containing `"nil"` in `type`) and fix them (set `type` to `nil`, that will become SQL `NULL` that means "base class" here):

```
User.where(type: "nil").update_all(type: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks. 'exact class name' was the missing part for me.